# How to rename files containing float numers to continuous number

Tags: regex, floating-point, file-rename

I'm pretty stuck here. Please help.

I have a big number of files, named like that:

```
plot_[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\.png
```

e. g. `plot_.0012.png` or `plot_1.12.png`.

Is there any way to rename it to `plot_{5 digits}.png`, like `plot_00012.png` and `plot_11200.png`?

Any help would be really great!

Greetings, Jürgen

Comment: and if you want a regex, then which programming language?

Comment: Can there be more than one digit before the dot, and if so, how does that affect the "5-digit" rule? Is it correct that if there is no number before the dot, a `0` should be substituted instead? And is it also correct that the resulting number shall be zero-padded to 5 digits at the right (so `1.12` becomes `11200`, but `.0012` becomes `00012`)?

Comment: It's under Linux, programming language doesn't matter. I thought about doing it in Midnight commander, if possible, or in bash or in python.   There is at most 1 digit before the dot, so its 1 pre-dot digit and 4 post-dot that shall be zero padded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;
use Data::Dumper;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_ --> ";
    s/^(plot_)(\d*)\.?(\d+)(\.png)$/$1 . '0'x(6-length("$2+$3")) . $2 . $3 . $4/e;
    say;
}

__DATA__
plot_.0012.png
plot_1.12.png
plot_12.023.png
plot_1.png
```

**Output:**

```
plot_.0012.png --> plot_00012.png
plot_1.12.png --> plot_00112.png
plot_12.023.png --> plot_12023.png
plot_1.png --> plot_00001.png
```